# Tumblr code not working

Tags: html, css, tumblr

Hi I m having trouble with a tumblr theme code that I want to use.

The problem I'm having with it is that some posts with images are overflowing and also it seems the page is slow for some reason? (I am not a coder in the slightest and any help would be amazing!)

The pastebin is [here](https://pastebin.com/vhztnP4J)

```
#entries {

    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px {select:border} {color:border};
    width: {select:post size};
    margin: 30px 5px 20px 650px;
    background: {color:post bg};
```

and here is a [link][2] to a page that has an example of what I am talking about

Comment: Hi. You will most likely get help quicker if you separate the question in to individual issues, and also include a link to the site rather than paste all the code. So, for example, if it is public, post a link to a page where the image is overflowing. Then create another question regarding page speed, what you expect the speed to be, and also a link.

Comment: I edited it to show a link to a page on my tumblr where the images overflow!

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your css:

```
img {
  display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
}
```

This should make images maintain their aspect ratio, and also fit inside the parent element.